# Eclipse: Notification on open/closure/deletion of resource in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, notifications, package-explorer

I am looking for some kind of notification event that my plugin can react on if a project in the eclipse workspace is closed/opened/deleted (in the package-explorer view or in general would be nice too)

I am not sure what to look for, I googled some time without finding anything of use? How do I get such a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `IResourceChangeListener` as described in [the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_events.htm) to look for the PRE_CLOSE event.

Comment: maybe someone else can need it, if you want to update the gui on a resource event you have to call

    getSite().getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable(){ "process event"})

otherwise you will get a SWT Error regarding invalid access

thx

Comment: Yes, any time you touch the GUI you have to be in the UI thread. And from the resource notifications you should do very little processing (because that mechanism is used to notify the whole workbench), so the `asyncExec` is the right choice.